# <Message>Invalid Policy: Unexpected: 'statement'</Message> error while trying to upload image in Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My Bucket Policy is as below:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1435346025768",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1435346024005",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::108444272233:user/parmishr"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::testeverything08/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

IAM user policy is as below:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Still i am getting the below error.

> `InvalidPolicyDocument`Invalid Policy:
>   Unexpected:
>   'statement'97E72E396E5F8215LKU/vqSgFegDQfiKz0k1wp80TX+axuR660qERLbMJ+ZSSXNHYfBVSYHWWOlMlsKE

can anyone guide me how to correct the policy

Comment: Assuming neither one of those things represents the *policy document* (and they shouldn't, as @AdamOcsvari correctly pointed out)... what does the actual policy document (embedded in the web form, in base64) look like?

Comment: Hi israel: i followed the following steps for the policy document. 
S3 Console -> Bucket -> under the properties tab -> Edit Bucket Policy -> there i have updated the policy. 
if this is wrong can you please share the step by step thing. 
Thanks a lot for your response.

Comment: Also i created it using the aws policy generator.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is your relevant answer:

> Amazon S3 uses two different kinds of policy documents. Bucket policies -- the type of policy in your example -- are distinct from the policies used for browser-based uploads using POST.
>
> For information on using policies in HTML forms for browser-based uploads, you can consult at  [Amazon S3 Developer Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HTTPPOSTForms.html#HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy)

Comment: Hi Adam, Thanks i have constructed the policy reffering the same.
Still no luck. :( 
any other suggestion.

Comment: @Paritosh The URL cited, above, documents a *very* different policy structure than what you have mentioned in comments.  The AWS policy generator generates *IAM* policies -- not S3 policy documents. Specifically, S3 policy documents do not include the word `statement`, which is shown in your error message.

Comment: @Michael: can you please guide me how should i create an S3 Policy document ?

Comment: I tried creating as per the S3 dev guide above keeping only conditions, Still in the policy window for bucket it is showing the following error. "Policy could not be parsed as a valid JSON string"

{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Condition": [
    {
  {"s3:x-amz-acl":["public-read"]}
 }
  ]
}

Comment: The double curly brackets aren't look valid for me. '}'

Comment: Hi adam, 
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Condition": [
  {"s3:x-amz-acl":["public-read"]}
  ]
}
on using the above it shows the following error 
Invalid policy element - Condition

Answer (score 0):

I am able to upload images now with the below document Policy..
Sample HTML Can be generated at the following site.
It was my mistake was confused between the policies. Thank you all for all your help and support.

https://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-example-code/post/post_sample.html

```
Document Policy
{ 
"expiration": "2016-12-01T12:00:00.000Z",
  "conditions": [
    {"acl": "public-read"},
    {"bucket": "waseassignment" },
    ["starts-with", "$key", ""]
  ]
}
```